# systemctl list service filter by target

Tags: linux, systemd

I can list host targets with:

```
systemctl list-units --type=target
```

And I can query the existing services with:

```
systemctl list-units [--all]
```

But I could not figure out how to list only the services belonging to a given `target`.

Trying to parse files and directories from `/etc/systemd/system` and `/lib/systemd/system` doesn'nt seem a good idea.

Could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Belonging" to a target is expressed in terms of the target depending on the other unit:

```
systemctl list-dependencies <name>.target
```

Comment: Technically it shows what I need with nice pretty looking and some surplus but hard to parse in a script, though. I came up with something like `systemctl show -p Wants my.target` and some `sed/grep`ing to generate a list.